# Performance issue of dismissViewController with Core Data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, modalviewcontroller

I have two View Controllers, the main one and popup one. Each of them contains a `UITableView` and a `fetchedResultController` to provide data.

the popup is setup inside storyboard, and I add BarButtonItem to dismiss the popup. Dismiss code is very simple

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]
```

the issue is It took couple seconds for the popup to dismiss, the app freeze once I click the "dismiss" button.

If I commented the setup of `fetchedResultController` in the Popup view controller, the dismiss happens immediately. So I assume the problem is with core data. but no idea what it could be.

I have also tried run Instruments to see the problem, no other codes of mine is executed except the above dismiss codes. (although I'm not experienced with Instruments well)

Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you verify the code you have in viewWillDisappear, viewDidUnload, and dealloc if any of them are taking time while dismissing.

Comment: nothing special in these methods. the popup view controller is pretty simple actually, just a table view with some data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, It turns out that the performance issue has nothing to do with core data and tableview. the guilty goes to a `UISwith`, which I apply a Scale to it to make it smaller than usual switch. After I remove the scale code, it behaves normal. so Now the problem is I need to figure out why the scale make it so slow, but it's another question.